# VST2.x GUI How does it work?

Tags: c++, user-interface, vst

Although I know how to create a VST plugin today, I still don't understand the GUI part of it.

I've been playing around with Steinbergs samples and what I can see is that they are using some default sliders in the exapmles, but am I supposed to use these when designing my own and apply some graphics to them? Or should I create my own completly? How should I think around the GUI approach to make the GUI code also work for both PC and MAC later on?

I've been searching my rearbehind off but can't find anything about these questions anywhere. Please give my a lead or guide me to the light so I can grow my hair back.

Answer (score 1):

> How should I think around the GUI approach to make the GUI code also
>   work for both PC and MAC later on?

If that is your ultimate goal, then I strongly suggest you check out the [JUCE](http://www.juce.com) library. The plugin wrappers are very good and it is completely cross-platform.

Comment: But the difference between Mac and PC coudn't be that much since it is C++ and the same VST SDK you're using, am I not right?

Comment: VST GUI and the VST SDK are not the same thing. VST GUI is (apparently) cross platform, but JUCE will make your life substantially easier in the long run. Plus, the support on the forums is great.

Comment: I've been reading more about VST GUI that I didn't even know existed until now when you said it. When I said VST GUI I meant (as I know now after reading more) the default GUI provided by the host DAW (the default sliders).